# While loop in C exited even when the condition is not true

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I'm new to C decided to learn it myself because of certain job requirements (knew some java before this). I hope I don't get downvoted for this question because I've searched everywhere about `while` loops in C, the usage of `scanf()` and variable assignments to see if I've missed anything but nothing explains why this code below runs even when the check on the variable `status` for the while loop is not *true* anymore. This program was taken from a text book but it doesn't explain why it works either it's just an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    long num; 
    long sum = 0L; 
    int status;

    printf("Please enter an integer to be summed ");

    printf("(q to quit): ");

    status = scanf("%ld", &num);

    while (status == 1) {
        sum = sum + num; 
        printf("Please enter next integer (q to quit): ");
        status = scanf("%ld", &num);
    }

    printf("Those integers sum to %ld.\n", sum);

    return 0;   
}
```

When I enter a number on the console (to be read as input by `scanf`) and from my understanding that number is clearly assigned to the variable `status`. The `while` loop however is checking each iteration if `status == 1` so why when I enter a number to be read by `scanf` *after* the while loop starts and that gets assigned to `status` the loop keeps going? The `status` variable is clearly not `1` anymore at this point. However it does stop when I enter `q` as suggested by the printed sentence to enter q to quit.

I've considered that it's perhaps checking if the value you entered is an `integer` or `long` to begin with, and if it's neither of those (e.g. if the input is a `char`) break the loop. But the problem is I cannot find a confirmation or explanation for this anywhere, of why isn't the check for the `while` loop checking if `status` is that exact integer `1`.

Comment: You have a typo: `%1d` --> `%ld`

Comment: You don't read a number into `status`. You read a number into `num` and then `status` is assigned the *number of values* read in the `scanf` call. As long as you input any valid number, `status` will be 1

Comment: Why do you think the `status` variable isn't one anymore? You say it's "Clearly not 1 anymore", but why shouldn't it still be one?

Comment: How do you know _' when the check on the variable `status` for the while loop is not "true" anymore.'_? Try printing the `status` value just after the `scanf` to make sure.

Comment: Ok out of all the things I've read about scanf and such I've always used it to obtain a value and assign it to a variable, e.g. `scanf` reads in an integer and stores it as a integer variable, then I can compare that integer input with another integer. Why is it different in this case that the scanf is is assigned the number of values read in the `scanf` call and not just storing that exact input value as a variable?

Comment: @Darkphoton: the value read and converted is stored into the variable whose address is passed as an argument to `scanf`. You probably never saw nor wrote code that stores the return value of `scanf()`.  This function has many quirks, it is widely misunderstood. Read the specification carefully and use wisely.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I can learn from this and will remember this from now but I guess my problem was that with assigning `status = scanf("%1d", &num) ` I viewed that as `scanf` stores input into `num`, then assigns that to `status`. I couldn't find anywhere during my search for this problem that assigning something to = `scanf` sets it to its `return` value. Sorry about the confusion, I really didn't mean to ask something silly.

Comment: @chqrlie thank you for the answer, I understand it now. Yeah it was confusing that it was used this way, I really didn't mean to ask something stupid just nothing made sense to me when I researched `scanf` and `while` loops as the explanations there didn't address the specific problem I had here.

Comment: @Darkphoton Apparently you've never seen a `scanf` used to read more than one value at once, like this: `int noOfValues = scanf( "%d%d%f", &myIntVar1, &myIntVar2, &myDoubleVar);` Otherwise you would realize the single return value (your 'status') can not be a copy of three variables (of different types!)...

Comment: @Darkphoton: no newbie question is a silly question. `scanf()` is very quirky.  Many experienced programmers get it wrong or use it erroneously.  Keep working, it's worth it.

Comment: @chqrlie: Ok great, thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Remove the ampersand from

```
printf("Those integers sum to %1d.\n", &sum);
```

it should be

```
printf("Those integers sum to %ld.\n", sum);
```

**Edit** As others pointed out, the one in `%1d` is a typo, and it causes your `scanf` to read a one-digit `int` value. Replace it with `%ld` ('ell' for 'long'). Similary in `printf` the 'l' modifier tells the function what size of `int` it got to print.

Comment: Thanks I've changed a couple typos (the book is extremely old I kept reading the l's as 1's) and now the program sums properly.

Answer (score 3):

> But the problem is I cannot find a confirmation or explanation for this anywhere, of why isn't the check for the while loop checking if status is that exact integer "1".

It is. And `status` is the return value from `scanf`, which is the number of fields read. That will be one if and only if one valid field was read.

Comment: So that's why, that makes a lot of sense now. I honestly could not find in any tutorial that this is comparing it to the number of fields read - up to this point when reading in a value with scanf I'm used to storing that as a variable and then using that to compare to something else. So why is `status = scanf("%ld", &num)` not assigning status to the long that is entered on console and in fact the return value?

Comment: @Darkphoton: `scanf` can read and convert multiple fields at a time. It takes extra arguments, one address for each converted field.  The return value is the number of fields converted or `EOF` if the end of file was encountered before the first conversion. The name `status` used in the textbook is misleading, but in your case, it can receive `1` if a number was converted and stored into `num`, `0` if you type something that is not a number, such as a letter, or `EOF` at end file.

Comment: @chqrlie: Thanks again, I answered your comment in your other reply above. Yes I agree the variable names made it extra confusing so I looked at the assignments in the wrong manner. It's a lot clearer now thank you :)